# Convert Primitive to Path using SVG format in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, path, xml

I've got a simple drawing in Illustrator consisting of multiple rectangles. I will need to handle that in [code](http://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) later one and saved the document as SVG.

The rectangles come out as `<rect />` nodes in SVG format.
Is there a clean way to convert the rectangles from primitive types to a path in Illustrator ? If so, how ?

So far my hacky solution was to use **Object > Path > Simplify** and because I was dealing with simple boxes with no transformations applied I've also ticked the **Straight Lines**. This worked well for boxes (kept the same number of vertices and look)

Is there a cleaner/less hacky way to convert a primitive to a path in Illustrator ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trick is to turn the path in to a `Compound Path` (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>). 
That makes the SVG output an actual path rather than a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Found anther method: Editing the primitive's anchor points.
I've tried several things and looked at the generated code and it looks like
simply moving an anchor point a wee bit back and forth does the trick (and also doesn't mess up the look of the shape)