# How to get rid of lines between vector shapes in Sketch 3?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

Whenever I design something on Sketch 3 using vectors and shapes, a thin transparent line appears between every shape. The weird thing is they appear between shapes that are supposedly 'touching' with no gap between them. Here's a design I've been working on for example:
[image]
In this case it's hard to notice it, mainly because the back is white. But if you open the image and zoom in, you'll be able to see it. Here's the same image with a black back so the lines are more noticeable:
[image]
The problem I'm confronting is basically the same as [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46353/get-rid-of-thin-white-lines-between-shape-joins) other question, but I guess the solution for Adobe Illustrator isn't the same for Sketch 3.

Comment: conflation error, your shapes must overlap.

Comment: read: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda silly, but I duplicate the total shape, overlay the duplicate directly overtop the original, and group the two shapes together for export.